# A sound and complete set of axioms and inference rules for quasi-equational logic

Tags: reference-request, universal-algebra

Equational logic has some axioms and inference rules to derive equations from other equations. What about quasi-equational logic? Is there, in some text, a set of sound and complete axioms and inference rules for quasi-equational logic, along with the proof that the set is indeed sound and complete?

Answer (score 0):

In [Partial Horn logic and cartesian categories](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007206001229), Palmgren and Vickers give a presentation of partial Horn logic, which is equivalent to quasi-equational logic, and prove it sound and complete.